# Discord.js setPresence not setting

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Hello i updated a bunch of stuff on my pc and now for DiscordJS
I need GUILD_PRESENCES for setPresence

But for some reason its not setting the Presence
However it's setting the online status to idle

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES] });

bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${bot.user.tag}!\n`);
    bot.user.setPresence({ 
        activity: {name: 'LOADING ... '},
        status: 'idle',
        type: 'WATCHING'}
    )
})
```

It was working perfectly before but now i have to use these "Intents" and it kind of broke it

Comment: Adding the error thrown would also assist in debugging your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading the [docs](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#clientuser) `ClientUser#setPresence` no long returns a promise.

```js
- client.user.setPresence({ activity: { name: 'with discord.js v12' } });
+ client.user.setPresence({ activities: [{ name: 'with discord.js v13' }] });
```